# How do I add an Organic group to my main menu?

Tags: 7, routes, organic-groups

I have read the documentation for [Organic Groups Version 7.x.1.x](http://drupal.org/node/1114852) (is there any more/better?) and created a group type "group content" and a group.

Question (and it may not be an OG question because I am a total n00b) - how do I add a top level menu "Groups" to my main menu? Specifically, what do I add for "path? ?

And then how do I add a group or two as sub-items to that menu?

Thanks a 1,000,000 in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love the [new screeencast](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups) for OG, it explains it really well.

When you install OG it creates a few "views" that you can use. "OG list" view shows you a list of all the groups (you might have to enable the view if it's disabled).

Then create your menu item "groups" and use "group-list" as the path.

You can add specific "group nodes" to a sub-menu by editing the nodes and using the "provide menu link" feature. I believe not every theme uses submenus, for example Bartik doesn't by default.